# Rspec test public controller method passing params to private controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

This is my controller:

```
class PlansController

  def use_new_card
    @user = User.find_by_id(new_card_params[:user_id])
    if new_stripe_card
    ...
  end

  private

  def new_card_params
    params.permit(:user_id, :stripeToken)
  end

  def new_stripe_card
    StripeService.new({user_id: @user.id, customer_id: @user.stripe_customer_id, source: new_card_params[:stripeToken]}).new_card
  end
end
```

I'm trying to write a controller spec that tests that when the proper parameters are `POST` to the `use_new_card` method, then `new_stripe_card`'s `StripeService.new` gets these parameters appropriately.

My spec looks like this so far:

```
describe "when proper params are passed" do
  before do
    @user = User.create(...)
  end

  it "should allow StripeService.new to receive proper parameters" do
    StripeService.should_receive(:new).with({user_id: @user.id, customer_id: @user.stripe_customer_id, source: "test"})
    post :use_new_card, user_id: @user.id, stripeToken: "test"
  end
end
```

But with that I'm getting

```
Failure/Error: post :use_new_card, user_id: @user.id, stripeToken: "test"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `new_card' for nil:NilClass
```

Totally fair, but I'm not sure how to fix this... I can't just stub `new_card` because a stubbed method on a `nil` object will still throw this error (I tried adding a `StripeService.any_instance.stub(:new_card).and_return(true)` already into the `before` block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stubbed methods return `nil` by default. Use `and_return` to specify the value returned by the stub::

```
StripeService.should_receive(:new).and_return(whatever)
```

or using the newer syntax

```
expect(StripeService).to receive(:new).and_return(whatever)
```

**EDIT**

Pardon my hand-waving. Your stub must return an object that will act like an instance of `StripeService` to the extent required for the purposes of the test. So for example:

```
let(:new_card) { double }
let(:new_stripe_service) { double(new_card: new_card) }
...
expect(StripeService).to receive(:new).and_return(new_stripe_service)
```

Now when the test refers to `new_stripe_service`, RSpec will return a test double that has a method stub named `#new_card`, which itself is a double. You can add whatever additional stubs you need to make the test pass. Alternatively, you can return an actual instance of `StripeService` for `new_stripe_service`.

Comment: If I add `and_return(new_card)`, since that's the name of the method that should be called, I get this error: `Failure/Error: StripeService.should_receive(:new).with({user_id: @user.id, customer_id: "test_customer", source: "test"}).and_return(new_card)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `new_card' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PlansControllerUseNewCard::WhenProperParametersArePassed:0x007f8aad94b2b0>`

Comment: OH yes, that helped immensely. Personally I'm not comfortable enough with `let` yet having never really used it, but I can just as easily do this by doing `@SSnew = StripeService.new({})` and doing `expect(StripeService).to receive(:new).and_return(@SSnew)`. Thanks!!!